# Fixed size of SWT Table in a ScrolledForm

Tags: java, scroll, swt, eclipse-rcp

I've got problems with a layout in a scrolled form of a `org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormPage`. I inherit my class from it and adding two section and several elements to it. I want to achieve having bottom section with 3 composites where the 1rst getting fixed amount of space and 2nd and 3rd share the rest of space equally among them. However I am getting the following result:

[image: Screenshot 1]

Here's partially the code:

```
@Override
    protected void createFormContent(IManagedForm managedForm)
    {
        formToolkit = managedForm.getToolkit();
        ScrolledForm form = managedForm.getForm();

        Composite body = form.getBody();
        GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(1, true);
        gridLayout.horizontalSpacing = 7;
        body.setLayout(gridLayout);
        formToolkit.paintBordersFor(body);

        //skipped

        // Business services left composite
        Composite compositeBSLeft = formToolkit.createComposite(compositeBSMain, SWT.NONE);
        compositeBSLeft.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
        compositeBSLeft.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1));
        formToolkit.paintBordersFor(compositeBSLeft);
                    // Business services middle composite
        Section sctnBusinessServices = toolkit.createSection(body, Section.TWISTIE | Section.TITLE_BAR);
        sctnBusinessServices.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));
        toolkit.paintBordersFor(sctnBusinessServices);
        sctnBusinessServices.setText("Business Services");
        sctnBusinessServices.setExpanded(true);

        //skipped

        Composite compositeBSMidBottom = formToolkit.createComposite(compositeBSMid, SWT.NONE);
        compositeBSMidBottom.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
        compositeBSMidBottom.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));
        formToolkit.paintBordersFor(compositeBSMidBottom);

        // Permission sets table
        TableViewer permissionSetsTableViewer = new TableViewer(compositeBSMidBottom,
                                                                    SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.H_SCROLL
                                                                                    | SWT.V_SCROLL
                                                                                    | SWT.BORDER);
        permissionSetsTableViewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());

        Table permissionSetsTable = permissionSetsTableViewer.getTable();
        permissionSetsTable.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));
        formToolkit.paintBordersFor(permissionSetsTable);
        permissionSetsTable.setHeaderVisible(true);
        permissionSetsTable.setLinesVisible(true);

        TableViewerColumn[] permissionSetsTableColumns = new TableViewerColumn[PERMISSIONSET_COLUMNNAMES.length];
        for (int j = 0; j < PERMISSIONSET_COLUMNNAMES.length; j++)
        {
            permissionSetsTableColumns[j] = new TableViewerColumn(permissionSetsTableViewer, SWT.NONE);
            permissionSetsTableColumns[j].getColumn().setWidth(100);
            permissionSetsTableColumns[j].getColumn().setText(PERMISSIONSET_COLUMNNAMES[j]);
        }

        permissionSetsTableViewer.setUseHashlookup(true);
        permissionSetsTableViewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
        permissionSetsTableViewer.setLabelProvider(new PermissionSetsLabelProvider());
        permissionSetsTableViewer.setInput(//blabla);

        // add the right composite and the second table

        //...
    }
```

If I omit the line `permissionSetsTableColumns[j].getColumn().setWidth(100);` then I get the desired result, but all the columns have zero-width.

[image]

I have two ideas how I could fix this.

1: Forbid the `ScrolledForm` to scroll horizontally.

2: Invoke `setWidth()` or `pack()` for the columns **after** the layout has been built.

Is both possible? How do I implement this?

The another question is: how do i solve the problem with the fixed width of the left composite? Because if I put lots of text in it on initialisation of the page, it breaks the layout either:

[image: Screenshot 3]